# Middleware not working as expected - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is driving me crazy as I think I'm doing the right thing but its not working correctly.

I have a `route` with a `middleware` attached to it like below;

```
Route::get('post/{id}/{name}', 'BlogController@post')->name('blog-post')->middleware('blogGuard');
```

As you can see I've defined 2 route params
In my controller I have below;

```
public function post () {
    return view('pages.blog.post');
}
```

With the middleware defined like this;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (is_null($request->input('id')) ||
        is_null($request->input('name'))) {

        return redirect()->route('blog-home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now if I click on a link like so; `http://blog.example.co.uk/post/153/firstpost` the `middleware` should not fire correct?

This is not the case. The `middleware` executes and I'm redirected. But if I remove the `middleware` then I'm able to access the page.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access route parameters you probably want to explicitly get them from the route.

```
$request->route('id');   // pulls the $route->parameter('id');
$request->route('name'); // pulls the $route->parameter('name');
```

`$request->id` will check the request inputs before falling back to returning a route parameter.
`$request->input('id')` will only check the input sources for the request and not the route params.

If you use `$request->id` expecting to get the route param 'id', one could break your logic by passing `id=anythinghere` to the querystring or adding a 'id' var to a post request.

Comment: Using this works but I'm not being redirected to `bloh-home` rather my `404` page... I have tried `(!$id || !$name)` and also `($id = "" || $name = "")` --- if I do something like `http://blog.example.co.uk/post/133` it means the name is missing and the redirect should kick in

Comment: you would probably want to make those optional route params. when they are required all the params have to be there to match the route.

Comment: So I guess I don't really need the `middleware` since laravel will send to 404 if any is missing correct?

Comment: well yea it will throw a notfound because it isn't matching anyway. just depends if you want to do something special with those particular requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!$request->id ||
        !$request->name)
```

Comment: This works but now my redirect is not working if I do something like `http://blog.example.co.uk/post/133` - here the name is missing --- It should redirect me to `home` but it redirects to 404 page

Comment: I would not recommend using the magic getter on Request for getting route params. It checks the input sources first for a match then falls back to returning a route param.